# Remove column from a 3D array with varied length for every first-level index (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I got a np.ndarray with ~3000 trajectories. Each trajectory has x, y and z coordinates and a different length; between 150 and 250 (points in time). Now I want to remove the z coordinate for all of these trajectories.

So `arr.shape` gives me `(3000,)`,(3000 trajectories) and (for example) `arr[0].shape` yields `(3,178)` (three axis of coordinates and 178 values).

I have found multiple explanations for removing lines in 2D-arrays and I found `np.delete(arr[0], 2, axis=0)` working for me. However, I don't just want to delete the z coordinates for the first trajectory; I want to do this for every trajectory.

If I want to do this with a loop for `arr[i]` I would need to know the exact length of every trajectory (It doesn't suit my purpose to just create the array with the length of the longest and fill it up with zeroes).

**TL;DR:** So how do I get from a ndarray with `[amountOfTrajectories][3][value]` to `[amountOfTrajectories][2][value]`?

The purpose is to use these trajectories as labels for a neural net that creates trajectories. So I guess it's a entirely new question but is the shape I'm asking for suitable for usage as labels for tensorflow?

Also: What would have been a better title and some terms to find results for this with google? I just started with Python and I'm afraid I'm missing some keywords here...

Comment: It sounds like you have an array of lists (check `arr.dtype`). Is there a reason why you can't have it be a regularily shaped array of floats?

Comment: Each individual trajectory is an ndarray?  If they are, can you explain why you chose an ndarray to contain them all?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [mcve],  [ask] and the other links on that page.  You could just create a new  array by iterating over the original and only adding the first two dimensions of each *sub-array*.

Comment: @Nils Werner: 
Okay, I just checked the dtype. `arr.dtype` is `object` while `arr[0].dtype` is `float64`.
Edit: I think it could negatively influence the learning if every array (meaning every trajectory) is of the same length. 

@wwii:

Comment: @wwii: Yes, they are. 
This is the form they come out of `scipy.io.loadmat`. To feed them into the network they have to be ndarrays I think. What would be a better structure?
Also, I'm going to read these links now. Thanks!

Comment: @wwii:
I've found these hints _somewhat_ helpful and will keep them in mind. 
I tried your solution and I've come across this:
`training_labels = np.ndarray([TRAINING_SET_SIZE, 2])
    for i in range(TRAINING_SET_SIZE):
        training_labels[i][0] = arr[i][0]
        training_labels[i][1] = arr[i][1]'

But this results in `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`
I think I should use `training_labels = np.ndarray([TRAINING_SET_SIZE, 2,TRAJECTORY_LENGTH]), but since that last part is not uniform this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this comes from `loadmat`, the source is probably a MATLAB workspace with a `cell`, which contains these matrices.

`loadmat` has, evidently created a 1d array of object dtype (the equivalent of a `cell`, with `squeeze` on).

A 1d object array is similar to a Python `list` - it contains pointers to arrays else where in memory.  Most operations on such an array use Python iteration.  Iterating on the equivalent list is usually faster.  (`arr.tolist()`).

```
alist = [a[:2,:] for a in arr]
```

should give you a list of arrays, each of shape (2, n) (`n` varying).  This makes new arrays - but then so does `np.delete`.

You can't operate on all arrays in the 1d array with one operation.  It has to be iterative.